# Bat script-zipping log files and move them to another location without any pop-ups and alerts

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to zip the log files of one location and then move them to another location

```
set _my_date=%date%``
set _my_date=%_my_date: =_%
set _my_date=%_my_date::=%
set _my_date=%_my_date:/=_%
set _my_date=%_my_date:.=_%
set logpath1="C:\Desktop\ArchivalofLogs\currentlogs"
set arcpath1="C:\Desktop\ArchivalofLogs\currentlogs\ArchiveLogs"
set zippath="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\WINZIP32.EXE"
c:
cd %logpath1%
FORFILES /D -2 /M *.log /C "cmd /c move @path %arcpath1%"
cd /D %arcpath1%
%zippath% a -tzip logs-%_my_date%.zip %arcpath1%\*.log
del *.log
```

When I am executing this code the log files are getting zipped and moved but it is asking for manual inputs like yes or no buttons.I want it to be executed without any alert boxes appearing while the process runs.Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the documentation of the program you are using. Some vendors have separate console and graphical programs.

Comment: when i am executing the code all the process is running fine.It zips the file moves the zip file to the specified location and delete the logs in the previous folder,but it is working by showing dialogue boxes and taking the manual inputs from users like yes or no...I want that entire process to be done after the execution of the code

Comment: Look at the documentation

Comment: That is in WinZip click Help and read what it says to do.

Comment: can anyone give a working code for that ?

Comment: You shouldn't be allowed to ask questions. What code would you want. I explained it to you - *Some vendors have separate console and graphical programs.*

Comment: No, When I am executing that code it is getting executed properly, but only problem is it is promping dialogue box in the middle.What should I do to eliminate that dialogue box?

Comment: I have answered over and over again. **Some vendors have separate console and graphical programs.**.

Comment: You have to go to their web site.